# C# Algorithm to assign matches between teams in a sport

Tags: c#, algorithm

Possible Dup: [Help Me Figure Out A Random Scheduling Algorithm using Python and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719886/help-me-figure-out-a-random-scheduling-algorithm-using-python-and-postgresql/719966#719966)

Let's say you have a division with 9 teams, and you want them to play 16 games each. Usually you would want to have 8 games (Home), and 8 games (Visitor). Is there a known algorithm to go in and assign the matches, randomly?

Note -> It can, sometimes not work, so you can have uneven numbers.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help Me Figure Out A Random Scheduling Algorithm using Python and PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719886/help-me-figure-out-a-random-scheduling-algorithm-using-python-and-postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See these [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Permutations) algorithms

Does this one work for you : [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice easy way to generate a round robin [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament). In the second round, you can repeat the round-robin and add swap home and away.

If you have an odd number of teams, you just use a dummy team that gives its opponent a bye in a particular round, which results in an extra round. You can distribute that extra round among the other rounds if you'd rather give double-headers than byes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the maximal matching in a bipartite graph algorithm for this (see, e.g., [here](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~simon/handouts/4245/hall.html)), which runs in polynomial time.

We represent your problem by assigning each team, T, 8 vertices (Th1, ..., Th8) in the "home" subset of vertices and 8 vertices (Ta1, ..., Ta8) in the "away" subset of the vertices.

We now look for a maximal matching between the "home" and "away" subsets such that each edge (H, A) in the matching satisfies the property that H is in the "home" subset, "A" is in the "away" subset, and H and A belong to different teams.